# Onde está a pasta code do magento 2?

Tags: magento

Gostaria de saber onde devo colocar os módulos no Magento 2? No Magento 1.9x, eu adicionava um módulo na pasta `app/code`, porem no Magento 2 a estrutura foi alterada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Já viu este site:

> Os módulos desenvolvidos para o Magento 1 não funcionarão no Magento
>   2, já que a própria estrutura de pastas foi substancialmente alterada.

- A pasta /app/etc/modules foi descontinuada. As configurações dos módulos ficam dentro da pasta /etc do próprio módulo, em um arquivo module.xml. Da mesma forma, os arquivos XML de configurações diversas tiveram seus nomes e estruturas alterados.

> **Fonte:** http://www.andregugliotti.com.br/livro-lojas-magento/modulos-magento-2/

Answer (score -1):

Basta criar a pasta 'code' dentro da pasta 'app' e usar os módulos personalizáveis que criar.